# Take the space on the right of beamer slides

Tags: beamer, margins

How can I remove the vertical (invisible) bar on the right of `beamer` slides where the logo goes? I am not using a logo and I want to maximize the use of space in my slides.

I am using the `Rochester` theme.

Answer (score 15):

You can use `\setbeamersize` (see Section **8.3 Frame and Margin Sizes** of the [`beamer` manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf)):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Rochester}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=5pt,text margin right=5pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\lipsum[2]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The default margins:

[image]

After setting the margins to `5pt` as in the example code:

[image]